# Tomcat: Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat

I just setup a new Java project with Tomcat 9 on Ubuntu 18.04.

However, when I start the Tomcat server using the command

```
sudo systemctl restart tomcat
```

I get the following error:

> The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path

I still can figure out what the issue is.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74595569/6518664) will help you install `Tomcat Native Library` which is what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was.

I had already set up an **SSL/TLS/HTTPS** connection protocol in the `opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml` file:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/key.key"
                     certificateFile="conf/cert.crt"
                     certificateChainFile="conf/chain.crt"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

but the `*.war` file that was gonna use the connection was not put in the `opt/tomcat/webapps` directory.

**Here's how I solved it**:

I simply added the `*.war` file in the `opt/tomcat/webapps` directory of tomcat, and then I restarted the tomcat server using:

```
sudo systemctl restart tomcat
```

And everything worked fine.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Your answer does absolutely not relate to the APR/OpenSSL problem.

Comment: Even I am facing the same problem. Did you find the solution.

Comment: Which war file are you talking about?

Answer (score 5):

You need to install `tomcat-native-1.2.31` from source code as following steps:

1. Install tool (skipped them if already exists)

```
yum install gcc apr-devel apr-util
```

2. Download tomcat-native from [official site](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/) to `/tmp` folder

```
cd /tmp
wget https://mirror-hk.koddos.net/apache/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/native/1.2.31/source/tomcat-native-1.2.31-src.tar.gz
```

3. Decompress file

```
tar zxvf tomcat-native-1.2.31-src.tar.gz
```

4. Configuration (be sure JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME are set)

```
cd tomcat-native-1.2.31-src/native

./configure --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config \
            --with-java-home=$JAVA_HOME \
            --with-ssl=yes \
            --prefix=$CATALINA_HOME
```

5. Compile and install

```
make & make install
```

6. Edit `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setenv.sh` (creating the file if necessary) and add the path to the tc-native libraries to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CATALINA_HOME/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And it's working!

Comment: I had the same problem and installing tomcat-native did fixed it. But I did it with a simple "yum install tomcat-native"

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting this issue with Java 17 and Tomcat 10.1.8.
The issue in my case was that another tomcat was already running that was started with Java 11 and was not shutdown. And I just changed the path of java from 11 to 17 and was trying to start Tomcat 10.

Once I stopped the older tomcat 9 instance, the tomcat 10 started fine.